# How can I focus a document programmatically from a Chrome extension (to paste content)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What I try to do is simple:

I am making a chrome extension.
This extension has a shortcut (e.g. <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>).
When I press this shortcut it switches to a tab,
and *should* paste clipboard content in the page.

Here's the background script that reacts to the shortcut and inject code in page to simulate paste event:

```js
// --- background.js

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  switch (command) {
    case 'switch_tab_and_paste_content':
      switchToTabAndPasteContent()
      break;
  }
})

async function switchToTabAndPasteContent() {
  const tab = (await chrome.tabs.query({})).filter((tab) => tab.title.toLowerCase().includes('my page'))[0]

  // focus the window
  await chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, { focused: true })
  // and focus the tab
  await chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true })



  /* inject paste emulation script */
  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: function () {
      pasteContent()
    }
  })
}
```

`pasteContent()` in the code above is a function contained in a content script. It's used to simulate paste event (just like a user would use ctrl + v on some page.)

```js
// --- paste.js

async function pasteContent() {
  try {
    const wizElement = document.querySelector('c-wiz')

    const clipboardItems = await navigator.clipboard.read()
    const firstItem = clipboardItems[0]
    const blob = await firstItem.getType('image/png')
    const file = new File([blob], 'image.png', { type: 'image/png' })

    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
    dataTransfer.items.add(file)

    const pasteEvent = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      clipboardData: dataTransfer,
    })

    wizElement.dispatchEvent(pasteEvent)
  }
  catch (e) { console.log(e) }
}
```

and here's the simplified `manifest.json`

```json
{
  "name": "app-connector",
  "version": 3,
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "scripting", "activeTab" ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ ... ],
    "js": "paste.js"
  }],
  "commands": {
    "switch_tab_and_paste_content": {
      "description": "Switch tab"
    }
  }
}
```

**However** when I press the shortcut on my keyboard, the tab is focused but I get this exception

```
DOMException: Document is not focused.
```

I know the reason of that exception (it's because when I leave the tab the document loses focus, `chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true })` activates the tab but it's not enough to focus back on the document)

What I want to know is if there is a way to bypass that (a chrome flag, a command-line argument, etc...).
Of course the ideal would be a native solution in the extension ecosystem but I didn't find/can't think of any solution. I tried opening/closing a popup fast to give focus back to the page but I still get this exception (it seems like it won't work unless I click in the page but it defeats the purpose of making an automated routine behind).

am I missing a permission?

Comment: Are you pasting in the background? I think it's easier to get an answer if you explain with code instead of sentences.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I included the code

Comment: Use `document.execCommand('paste')`

Comment: Paste target is canvas?
So is 'c-wiz' wrong?

Comment: @wOxxOm no it doesn't work, I need to dispatch the event from the `wizElement` (in my example) not from the document, and I think it doesn't help bypassing the document focus requirement anyway. But thanks for your help. I ended up using puppeteer...

Comment: There's no requirement for document focus when using execCommand. You only need to focus the element itself.